# Android - Find a substring and make it bold

Tags: android, text, textview

What would be the correct way to find str1 as a substring of str2, make it bold (in str2, that is), and then display it as a textview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `str2` as `SpannableString` and use `setSpan()` method to find substring `str1` and make it `BOLD`.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html).

**Try this:**

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String str1 = "substring";
    String str2 = "Find a substring and make it bold";

    if (str2.contains(str1)) {

        SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(str2);
        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 
                str2.indexOf(str1), 
                str2.indexOf(str1) + str1.length(), 
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        textView.setText(spannable);
    } else {
        textView.setText(str2);
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str1 = "hello world, how are you?";
    String str2 = "world";        

    //check if str1 contains str2
    if (!str1.contains(str2)) {
        return;
    }

    //find index of str2
    int startIndex = str1.indexOf(str2);
    int endIndex = startIndex + str2.length();

    //create spannable
    SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(str2;
    spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startIndex, endIndex, 0);

    //set it to textview
    textView.setText(spannable);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Spannable String for that

```
if(str2.contain(str1){

SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str2);


// Span to make text bold

StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);



// make them also bold
sb.setSpan(bss, str2.indexOf(str1), str1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(sb);
}else{

textView.setText(str2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf to find sub1 and Html.fromHtml to format string

```
    int start = str2.indexOf(str1);
    String destStr = str2.substring(start)+"<b>" + str2.substring(start, str1.length()) + "</b> " + str2.substring(start+str1.length());
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(destStr));
```

Comment: Please use Spannable String as Html.fromHtml(String string) is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the people who commented here, I created a function that also ignores case - to use, textView.setText(boldifySubstring(str2, str1)); -

```
public static Spanned boldifySubstring(String string, String substring) {
    //Create spannable string
    SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(string);
    //Check if substring exists (ignore case)
    if (string.toLowerCase().contains(substring.toLowerCase())) {
        //Get start + end indexes (ignore case)
        int start = string.toLowerCase().indexOf(substring.toLowerCase());
        int end = start + substring.length();
        //Make relevant parts bold
        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    return spannable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Kotlin code which will find all occurrences of a string in a CharSequence and apply specified styles (Spans) to the found occurrences.

`"Hello World? Hello World!".applySpansToSubString("world", StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD))`

will return "Hello **World**? Hello **World**!"

```
 fun CharSequence.applySpansToSubString(searchString: String, vararg spans: CharacterStyle): CharSequence {
    if(searchString.isEmpty()) { return this }
    val sb = SpannableString(this)
    var startIndex = 0
    while(startIndex in 0 until length) {
        startIndex = indexOf(searchString, startIndex, true)
        if (startIndex >= 0) {
            val endIndex = startIndex + searchString.length
            for (span in spans) {
                sb.setSpan(CharacterStyle.wrap(span), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            }
            startIndex = endIndex
        }
    }
    return sb
}
```